# How to stub a method invoked via reflection in .net

Tags: c#, reflection, stub

I've got a Base class that looks like following:

```
public Base<TReceiver, TRequest, TResponse>
    where TReceiver : class
    where TRequest : class, new()
    where TResponse : class, new()
{    
    private readonly TReceiver _receiver;
    public TRequest Request { get; set; }
    public TResponse Response { get; set; }

    protected Base(TReceiver receiver)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public void CallReceiver()
    {
        var receiverType = _receiver.GetType();
        var executeMethod = receiverType.GetMethod(ExecuteMethodName);
        Response = (TResponse) executeMethod.Invoke(_receiver, new object[] {Request});
    }

    protected abstract string ExecuteMethodName { get; }
}
```

Derived class lookes like this:

```
public class Derived : BaseCommand<IReceiver, DerivedRequest, DerivedResponse>
{
    public Derived (IReceiver receiver)
        : base(receiver)
    {
    }

    protected override string ExecuteMethodName
    {
        get { return "Execute"; }
    }
}
```

This is IReceiver interface:

```
public interface IReceiver
{
   DerivedResponse Execute(DerivedRequest request);
}
```

Is it possible to stub Execute method in IReceiver implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This stub does not return what I need: `var receiverStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IReceiver>(); receiverStub.Stub(x => x.Execute(new DerivedRequest())).IgnoreArguments().Return(new DerivedResponse());`

Comment: Why are you doing this through reflection in the first place? You've got the receiver interface, *make them use the interface*. Make a constraint `where TReceiver : IReceiver` and you're done, no reflection needed. If they need the name different for some reason, they should simply implement the interface explicitly and make it call the "proper" method. That's what interfaces are for.

Comment: Luaan, there will be a situation when I need to pass objects with different interfaces, but all of them have the same Execute method signature.

Comment: Why don't you use a generic interface, then? You could have `IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse>` with a method `TResponse Execute(TRequest request)`. All the flexibility, no reflection.

Comment: Because method name is also different in each interface

Comment: Yeah, the question is *why*? Why don't you simply force them to use the same interface? It *is* principially the same interface, after all. And as I said before, at the very least you could have an explicit interface implementation to "mask" the "real" method name.

Comment: Luaan, because I receive these objects via SOAP service calls. They are already implement these interfaces. I cannot change them. If there is a better way to do this could you please give an example?

Comment: Oh, and they are directly those auto-generated classes? Perhaps you could mark them as partial, and then just add the explicit interface implementation in a separate non-generated file?

Comment: Yes, they are auto-generated. Your idea is good but in that case i can't create a base class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake)
This code is correct:

```
public void CallReceiver()
{
    var receiverType = typeof(TReceiver);
    var executeMethod = receiverType.GetMethod(ExecuteMethodName);
    Response = (TResponse) executeMethod.Invoke(_receiver, new object[] {Request});
}
```

Then I can stub my receiver like this:

```
var receiverStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IReceiver>();
receiverStub.Stub(x => x.Execute(new DerivedRequest())).IgnoreArguments().Return(new DerivedResponse());
```